# Horizontal squares with equal spacing between

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a row of 5 equal squares (each 50x50) with spacing 20dp between them. I don't want anything to stretch, but at the same time I want to make it so that if I hide one of the squares, the others move over.

For example:

```
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
| 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  |
| x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
```

Then, if I set the middle square to `isHidden = true`, I'd want the others to move over:

```
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
| 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  |
| x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
```

Is this possible? My first thought was a stack view, but I don't think that would work since they're meant to adjust spacing.

Comment: Center your stack view horizontally in its parent and don’t add leading or trailing constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIStackView`...

- No **Width** or **Trailing** constraint.
- Distribution: Fill
- Spacing: 20
- give each subview Width and Height constraints of `Equal to Constant: 50`

You end up with:

```
   1          2          3          4          5
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
| 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  |
| x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
```

Remove view #3 with:

```
let v = stackView.arrangedSubviews[2]
v.removeFromSuperview()
```

You now have:

```
   1          2          4          5
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
| 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  | 20 | 50  |
| x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |    | x50 |
+-----+    +-----+    +-----+    +-----+
```

You'll get the same result with:

```
let v = stackView.arrangedSubviews[2]
v.isHidden = true
```

The stack view will *hide* view #3, removing the space it is occupying. If you set `.isHidden` back to `false`, the view will re-appear in its original position, shifting views 4 and 5 back to their original spots.

Answer (score 1):

You should use StackView. But to hide some square you need to set its alpha to 0, instead of make it hidden. In this case layout will stay the same - you can hide some squares, and other will stay on their positions. If you need other squares to fill empty space with given spacing between elements - use isHidden property.

- For example there are 5 circles: 0-0-0-0-0.
- Lets set 3 circle isHidden: 0-0-0-0.
- And now set alpha of 3 circle to zero: 0-0- -0-0.

Comment: I think OP wants the layout to move over, so I think `isHidden` is fine

Comment: No, the OP specifically wants the other squares to move over and fill the now-empty space. They should use `hidden=true`, **not** `alpha=0`.

Comment: There are 3 circles: 0-0-0. If you make second hidden, result will be: 0-0. And if you set alpha of second to 0 the result will be: 0- -0. This is key feature of UIStackView)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, and `StackView` mentioned in the other answer is a great choice if you can use it. If not, yo can also:

1. Have a a width constraint on your 50px item (which you probably do already) for each item. When you want to hide an item, also set its width constraint to `0.0`. When you are showing the item, set it back to `50.0`.

   ```
   yourWidthConstraint.constant = visible ? 50.0 : 0.0
   ```
2. Always hide the last item, and simply shift the content of other items. For example if each item is a `UIImageView`:

   ```
   for i in hiddenIndex...lastVisibleIndex-1 {
       element[i].image = element[i + 1].image
   }
   element[lastVisibleIndex].isHidden = true
   ```